# How to run Jenkins pipeline automatically when "git push" happens for specific folder in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins

I have started using Jenkins recently and there is only scenario where I am stuck. I need to run "Jenkins pipeline" automatically when `git push` happens for specific folder in master branch. Only if something is added to specific folder, than pipeline should run.

I have already tried SCM with `Sparse checkout path`, and mentioned my folder, but that's not working.

I am using GUI free style project, I dont know groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by configuring the Git poll.

I used poll SCM to trigger a build and I used the additional behavior of Jenkins Git plugin named "Polling ignores commits in certain paths" > "Included Regions" : `my_specific_folder/.*`

By the way, using `Sparse checkout path` allows jenkins to checkout only the folder you mentioned.